# Find item in array with indexOf

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

I have a problem with 'indexOf'. When i pass a numerical value in argument, it works, but not with a variable:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'bdd.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'jsonNomCommune': jsonNomCommune, 'client': client},
    success: function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        listClients= data.clients;
        listProspects = data.prospects;

        $('#tableCSV tbody tr ').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            id=id.substring(4);

            if (listClients.indexOf(id) > -1){
                $(this).css("background-color","red");

            }

            if (listProspects.indexOf(id) > -1){
                $(this).css("background-color","blue");
            }


        });
    }
});
```

listProspects and listClients are arrays of numericals values. For example, 27 is in listClients, so when id=27, "listClients.indexOf(id) > -1" should works, but it doesn't. And when i write: "(listClients.indexOf(27) > -1)" it works.

Where is the problem??

Comment: can you add a console.log(id) right before the indexOf, to check it has the expected value?

Comment: I reckon `id` might be a string. If so, you can use `parseInt(id)` to make sure it's an int.

Comment: `id` is a string as `substring` returns a string!

Comment: @evolutionxbox When using `parseInt()` you should *always* pass the `radix` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`27` and `"27"` are different.

Try parsing id to integer:

```
listClients.indexOf(+id) //note, its parsing
```

OR:

```
listClients.indexOf(parseInt(id, 10))
```

Comment: Wouldn't `+id` turn `id` into a string? Surely it needs to be an int?

Comment: "When using parseInt() you should always pass the radix parameter." Thanks to @Phylogenesis.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Unary + always returns a number. This is a common idiom for converting a numeric string to a number.

Answer (score 0):

You should cast the value of `$(this).attr('id')` into a number.
So it should be `var id = Number($(this).attr('id'));`

Answer (score 0):

cast id to integer by using parseInt() method